# XML só traz valor vazio

Tags: php, xml

Tenho o `xml` abaixo trazido de um `cUrl`.

```
<DistanceMatrixResponse>
<status>OK</status>
<origin_address>Muriaé - MG, 36880-000, Brasil</origin_address>
<destination_address>Patrocínio do Muriaé - MG, 36860-000, Brasil</destination_address>
<row>
<element>
<status>OK</status>
<duration>
<value>3939</value>
<text>1 hora 6 minutos</text>
</duration>
<distance>
<value>43371</value>
<text>43,4 km</text>
</distance>
</element>
</row>
</DistanceMatrixResponse>
```

Estou tentando das seguintes formas ler o status mas só dá vazio.

Quando dou um print_r(), lê todo o xml na tela.

```
 $frete = new CalculaFrete(36880000, 36860000);
 $freteXML1 = $frete->calculaFrete2();
 $freteXML2 = simplexml_load_file($frete->calculaFrete2());
 print "<pre>";
 print_r($freteXML1);
 print $freteXML1->row->element->status;
 print $freteXML2->row->element->status;
 print "</pre>";
```

Onde estou errando?

Comment: O `$freteXML1` retorna o `xml` logo acima?

Comment: normal, corretíssimo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse `$xml` fiz o teste e deu certo, mas, foi utilizado [`simplexml_load_string`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.simplexml-load-string.php) porque está retornado pelo método uma texto com `xml`.

```
$xml = '<DistanceMatrixResponse>
<status>OK</status>
<origin_address>Muriaé - MG, 36880-000, Brasil</origin_address>
<destination_address>Patrocínio do Muriaé - MG, 36860-000, Brasil</destination_address>
<row>
<element>
<status>OK</status>
<duration>
<value>3939</value>
<text>1 hora 6 minutos</text>
</duration>
<distance>
<value>43371</value>
<text>43,4 km</text>
</distance>
</element>
</row>
</DistanceMatrixResponse>';

$obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);

print $obj->status;
print '<br />';
print $obj->row->element->status;
```

[***Exemplo: IDEONE***](http://ideone.com/fork/RAq1N0)

Comment: era isso mesmo, obrigado!

Comment: De repente me bateu uma dúvida: Estou pesquisando o logradouro na base dos correios, e estou pesquisando a distancia na base de dados do google maps usando os mesmos ceps. Mas o google maps também me traz o logradouro também. Seria confiável confiar na base de dados do google maps no tocante à logradouros e fazer toda a pesquisa por lá e deixo a base dos correios de lado? Ou não seria uma boa?

Comment: @CarlosRocha eu acredito mais na base de dados do correios, agora também depende se a base é atualizada...